# Unit Testing stack based virtual machine c#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, microsoft-fakes

I'm currently working on a stack based virtual machine which loads commands from a text file and I need to test the class Increment and Decrement operations. 
I am fairly new to unit testing but I've worked on a few examples to get the hang of the syntax but now I've become a bit stuck!

When I try to run the tests I get a null value exception, so I guess my next question is would I be best to use Moq or Fakes to pass a value through to test to see if it passes the expected result?

I have had a look at the Fakes assembly and this is what I came up with but I'm not sure how I would pass a System.Collections

After this I have become stuck, any help / constructive help would be excellent.

EDIT- The integer value has been pushed to the stack prior to calling this class.

Comment: Not sure if I'm just missing something but how are you expecting to pop something off the stack without pushing something onto it first?

Comment: There is a Push statement directly after the Pop, its works fine with statement in place, the variable is called like in the class I am trying to test. int op1 = (int)VirtualMachine.Stack.Pop(); VirtualMachine.Stack.Push(op1--);

Comment: Where is the null value exception happening? Would help us track down the issue faster.

Comment: Sorry when I run the tests in the Test Explorer I get this: Result StackTrace: at UnitTestSVM.UnitTest1.DecrTest() in UnitTestSVM\UnitTest1.cs:line 17 Result Message: Test method UnitTestSVM.UnitTest1.DecrTest threw exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you might be getting a little friction because the problem has been modelled slightly strangely. For my money, I'd [avoid the difficulty of mocking](http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/2008/02/13/mocks-are-a-code-smell/) by re-arranging your problem. For example, if you pass the stack into the operation itself, you'll get a much more natural test;

```
var stack = new Stack();
var op = new Decr();
stack.push(0);
op.Execute(stack);
Assert.AreEqual(-1, stack.Peek());
```

You'll have avoided unnecessary state on the `Decr` class. This is an example of the Dependency Inversion Principle, where dependent objects are passed into a class, rather than being created by it.

Comment: I came up with a little adjustment to you answer but it still passes a null object exception: var stack = new SVM.VirtualMachine.Fakes.StubIVirtualMachine();
            var op = stack.StackGet();
            op.Pop();
            op.Push(1);
            Assert.AreEqual(-1, op.Peek());

Comment: Again, I'd avoid a stub here -- can you not pass a normal stack? There's no need for interfaces, stubs, etc. Also, what line causes this null ref exception? Can you attach a debugger and find out exactly where it occurs?

Comment: As far as i know you cant, its says line 13 but thats the beginning of the method.

Comment: Sorry the null exception happens in this statement  var stackVal = stack.StackGet();

Comment: Yeah - see how it'd be easier just to new up the stack and pass it in?

Comment: Yeah I understand that but I can't call var stack = new ProgramStack(); as ProgramStack(); isnt a valid class / method. so how would I go about creating a stack to pass it? If you dont mind me asking?

Comment: Hi. Is the virtual machine your code? Because I'm wondering how it creates/populates it's .Stack property...

Comment: Just private Stack stack = new Stack(); and then public Stack Stack {get{return stack;}} in the public sealed class SvmVirtualMachine

Comment: Ah, ok. So I would update IInstruction to .Execute(Stack stack). Remove the VirtualMachine property from IInstruction.  Update all the subclasses. Then write the test as above (I'll correct the code) and you won't now need a fake vm or a fake stack, and the test will be simpler. The operation just pushes and pops from whatever stack it has been passed, no need for mocks or stubs.